# How do I prevent recipients from changing the routing order?

Tags: docusignapi

[DocuSign the sender view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUj0L.png)

Details

No1.
Create an envelope with the following API.

> https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/

At this time, include the following in the request body. This will invalidate any recipient edits that have already been set.

> recipients.signers[0].templateRequired = 'true';
> recipients.signers[0].templateLocked = 'true'.

No2.
Get the URL of the sender view of the envelope created in No1 with the following API.

> https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createsender/

No3.
Access the sender view URL obtained in No2 by specifying the following in the query parameter This will enable the envelope destination edit action.

> ?showHeaderActions=true&showEditRecipients=true

At this time, the Add Recipients button is pressed from the Edit Recipients action on the Senders view screen of the DocuSign UI. By default, they are sequentially numbered. (See image)
Is there any way to prevent this added recipient order from being changed by changing the settings from the screen or by specifying options when creating a recipient?

I have read the documentation but have not found a good way to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recipients should not be able to change the routing order unless they are an Editor Recipient (who can change the envelope and everything about it)

If they are all signers or other recipients with no editing privileges, the routing order will respect what you have put in.

If you are looking to make a template and lock the routing order in the template, that is possible too.

But otherwise if there are no editor type recipients, the routing order will stay the same

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.
Your answers were very helpful.
However, it seems that your situation is different from mine. My explanation of the situation was insufficient.
I will revise my question.
I appreciate your help.